# ASP.NET Core with Docker over HTTPS using User Secrets

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, https, certificate, user-secret

I am trying to replicate a [sample from Microsoft: Developing ASP.NET Core Applications with Docker over HTTPS](https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md), but it fails to start, because it cannot find the certificate passed via user secrets.
Here are the steps to reproduce (or just follow the link to the sample above):

1. Clone the repository from `https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/` and switch to the sample in the folder `samples\aspnetapp`
2. (Remove existing dev certs via `dotnet dev-certs https --clean`)
3. Create new app certificate with password `testtest`

   ```
   dotnet dev-certs https -ep $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https\aspnetapp.pfx -p testtest
   dotnet dev-certs https --trust
   ```
4. Configure application secret for the certificate with same password `testtest`

   ```
   dotnet user-secrets init -p aspnetapp\aspnetapp.csproj    
   dotnet user-secrets -p aspnetapp\aspnetapp.csproj set "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password" "testtest"
   ```

   The first line adds the `UserSecretsId` tag to `aspnetapp.csproj`:

   `<UserSecretsId>0d63114d-ac72-4327-96ef-7086a1c48fa6</UserSecretsId>`

   It also creates a `secrets.json` file within `%APPDATA%\microsoft\UserSecrets\0d63114d-ac72-4327-96ef-7086a1c48fa6\`

   This is the `secrets.json` content:

   ```
   {
     "Kestrel:Certificates:Development:Password": "testtest"
   }
   ```
5. Build container image

   ```
   docker build --pull -t aspnetapp .
   ```

   *Until here eveythings works as expected.*
6. Start the docker container passing the secrets:

   `docker run --rm -it -p 8001:8001 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8001 -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -v $env:APPDATA\microsoft\UserSecrets\:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets -v $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https:/root/.aspnet/https/ aspnetapp`

   *This does not work, it does not find the certificate:*

   ```
   fail: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host[11]
     Hosting failed to start
     System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to configure HTTPS endpoint. No server certificate was specified, and the default developer certificate could not be found or is out of date.
     To generate a developer certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https'. To trust the certificate (Windows and macOS only) run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust'.
   ```

---

When I pass the certificate password via environment variable to docker run, it will start as expected and exposes the service via https:

```
docker run --rm -it -p 8001:8001 -e ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORTS=8001 -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Password="testtest" -e ASPNETCORE_Kestrel__Certificates__Default__Path=/https/aspnetapp.pfx -v $env:USERPROFILE\.aspnet\https:/https/ mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/samples:aspnetapp
```

---

**This is the `dockerfile`:**

```
FROM --platform=$BUILDPLATFORM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
ARG TARGETARCH
WORKDIR /source

# copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY aspnetapp/*.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore -a $TARGETARCH

# copy and publish app and libraries
COPY aspnetapp/. .
RUN dotnet publish -a $TARGETARCH --no-restore -o /app


# final stage/image
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0
EXPOSE 8080
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app .
USER $APP_UID
ENTRYPOINT ["./aspnetapp"]
```

---

Is there anything I am missing in the sample? What do I have to change for Asp.Net Core to be able to use the certificate using user secrets in the docker container?

Additional question: After development works, I am wondering what needs to change for production. I will have a letsencrypt certificate, that I would prefer to use via a volume.